# Connecting Lattice graphs in different grid viewports

Tags: r, lattice, r-grid

Lattice is based on Grid universe. Connecting the panels of lattice graphs placed on different viewports should be easy. But it seems panels crop the line between them.

I want to connect the big points of the following two lattice graphs. But [the red line is cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8NvV.png) . How can I connect both points?

Thanks in advance!

```
library(grid)
library(lattice)

p1 <- xyplot(mpg ~ disp, mtcars,
             panel= function(...){
                 grid.points(300,20, default.units="native",size=unit(4,"mm"),pch=16)
                 panel.xyplot( ... )
             }
             )
##p1

grid.newpage()
vlay <- viewport(layout=grid.layout(nrow=2, ncol=2),name="ejjoin")
pushViewport(vlay)
vpfig1 <- viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1:2,name = "vp11")
vpfig2 <- viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 2,name = "vp12")
pushViewport(vpfig1)
print(p1,newpage=FALSE,prefix="figrow1")
upViewport() ##
pushViewport(vpfig2)
print(p1,newpage=FALSE,prefix="figrow2")
upViewport() ##


## Connect the points
##grid.ls(viewports=TRUE, grobs=FALSE)
seekViewport("figrow1.panel.1.1.vp")
grid.move.to(unit(300,"native"), unit(20, "native"))
seekViewport("figrow2.panel.1.1.vp")
grid.line.to(unit(300,"native"), unit(20, "native"),arrow=arrow(),gp=gpar(col="red",lwd=4))
upViewport() ##
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I must just select another viewport.
[The solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StQhS.png)
Thanks!

```
grid.ls(viewports=TRUE, grobs=FALSE, fullnames=TRUE)
seekViewport("figrow1.panel.1.1.vp")
grid.move.to(unit(300,"native"), unit(20, "native"))
##seekViewport("figrow2.panel.1.1.vp") ## Wrong!
seekViewport("figrow2.panel.1.1.off.vp")
grid.line.to(unit(300,"native"), unit(20, "native"),arrow=arrow(),gp=gpar(col="red",lwd=4))
upViewport() ##
```